# Install Nintex workflow SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365-developer, nintex

I need to install Nintex workflow for my office 365 SharePoint site,
but I don't have access to central administration of SharePoint Online.
Is it possible? If yes then How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

1. Click on `Add an app` in SharePoint site
2. Type Nintex workflow in find an app search box
3. Click on `2 results in the SharePoint Store`
4. You can see `Nintex Workflow for Office 365` in store. Open it.
5. Click on `Add it` button
6. Install it

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you?